# executorService.invokeAll(...) takes longer time to finish even when timeout is set

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice

I've encountered a problem I'm not sure how to solve.

I'm trying to parallelize a part of the code that we've done sequentially up until now. To do so I've divided the task into several smaller orthogonal tasks.

I've created an executorService and I'm running:

```
executorService.invokeAll(callableList, timeBudget, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Each callable is has several IO tasks within it (Like going to a database and external services) the overall time-budget is 200ms+-. The reason to use `invokeAll` is since I have an overall timeBudget for all of the request. Thus, I need a way to limit all the futures with a single budget.

In order to test myself I've added different metrics that report back to some logging visualisation tool that we have. I've noticed that:

- The median (and 75th percentile) latency of that part of the code has faster.
- The 95th+ percentiles has actually gotten worse.

After thorough investigation (Where I've benchmarked different parts of the code) I've noticed that `invokeAll` 99th percentile running time was actually 500ms and even more sometimes. This thing really screws up the optimization. Any ideas on what may cause this? Any other suggestions? Are there alternatives to `invokeAll`?

Comment: How big is your thread pool and how many tasks are there? In sequential mode how long do the tasks take each? Have you added logging to confirm that your IO operations are blocking the thread so you get the concurrency you need on those external calls? You may be starving those 95+ percentile threads.

Comment: You may also be running into limits such as exhausted database connection pools and http client pools when you run everything in parallel. Overall you need to measure and find the bottlenecks.

Comment: @JoeW We can divide the code into 3 tasks - Database, Requests and a code to merge all threads into one data-structure.  The database task without parallelism takes around 40ms and with parallelism takes about 20ms. The third-party requests take 60ms and take 45-50ms in parallel the merging task takes almost nothing.

Comment: The note from @ewramner is a good one. Also, can you post the creation and config of your executor service? What happens if you use a smaller fixed size threadpool? Could even run with a threadpool of 1 to make sure your updated refactoring is behaving as expected and you get the same as the historical sequential code and you're not hanging a resource somewhere.

Comment: Oi, My mistake. The executor is a custom fixedThreadPool code that's written by my company (So I can't post) is by any chance the fixedThreadPool is the problem? (What happens when a thread-pool is busy on other tasks and I do `invokeAll`?)

Comment: Your tasks are probably queued. You could instrument when the task was created, when it started running and when it ended for each task. Then you will get the wait time as started minus created and the total time as ended minus created. If the wait time is long the fixed thread pool is to blame. EDIT: System.currentTimeMillis() should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have answer to why `invokeAll` with timeouts sometimes takes much more time than the given budget. I have an answer to the question: How to run a list of futures simultaneously with a given budget?

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = <init>;
List<ListenableFuture<G>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (T chunk : chunks) {
    futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> function(chunk, param1, param2, ...)));
}
Futures.allAsList(futures).get(budgetInNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

The code above has used Guava library.

The problem with this approach is that I'm not getting the status of each future, because I'm getting a timeout exception if the time is up - but at least in terms of budgeting the behaviour is as expected.